# How to show id with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show id with pop up when i click button delete. but when i click the delete button, it doesnt work. when i check the console in inspect element, they say listData not undefined. Anyone help me please? i'm new in angularjs
view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr,td,th{
            border: 1x solid #000;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        td{
            width: 300px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-App="myAPP">
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>Alamat</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in listData">
            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.nama}}</td>
            <td>{{x.alamat}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" ng-click="del(x.id)">Delete</a>
                <a href="#" ng-click="update(x.id)">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/MainController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller :

```
app.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.listData = [
        {
            'id' : 01,
            'nama' : 'Faizah Pratiwi',
            'alamat' : 'Malang'
        },
        {
            'id' : 02,
            'nama' : 'Anastasya Putri',
            'alamat' : 'Jember'
        },
        {
            'id' : 03,
            'nama' : 'Sharon Natalia',
            'alamat' : 'Tulungagung'
        },
        {
            'id' : 04,
            'nama' : 'Faizah Pratiwi',
            'alamat' : 'Malang'
        },
    ];

    $scope.del = function(id){
        var index = getSelectedIndex(id);
        alert(index);
        $scope.listData.slice(index,1);
    };
    function getSelectedIndex(id){
        for (var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
            if($scope.listData[i].id==id)
                return i;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Is the value of id give here correct? I mean if you want to put an integer then just mention 1,2,3 or 4 otherwise use it as string like '01','02','02 etc. Also what do you see in view at the place of id?

Comment: I think `return -1;` is in wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says undefined because, It should be `$scope.listData`,

```
 function getSelectedIndex(id){
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listData.length; i++) {
            if($scope.listData[i].id==id)
                return i;               
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Also it's not slice, it is splice

```
$scope.listData.splice(index, 1);
```

Rather than doing that you can directly delete the index from array with this piece of code,

```
$scope.del = function(index) {
    alert(index);
    $scope.listData.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RN1bU2gOihr0bbPjKnvC?p=preview)**

**[DEMO WITH STRAIGHT FUNCTION](https://plnkr.co/edit/wlBwySSQkeogfGEyahVB?p=preview)**

Comment: Above function has issue it worked only for first case for subsequent cases it always return -1 as -1 returned inside for loop.

Comment: @SumitDeshpande it is just a sample

Comment: @Sajeetharan for a sample it should be a correct one, please consider editing

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angularjs for front end you dont need to pass id for that, angular's ng-repeat generate a index for your array. So you can directly pass $index inside your method like :

```
<a href="#" ng-click="del($index)">Delete</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="update($index)">Edit</a>
```

and then splice a particular index from array:

```
$scope.del = function(index){
     alert(index);
     $scope.listData.splice(index,1);
};
```

This will save your extra effort :)
Check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IfR1ZrSiBFX13beZoXcN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Created the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7r8e8j2fsFMr15ny2YKd?p=preview) example for the same.

Changed functions as below -

```
$scope.del = function(id) {
    var index = getSelectedIndex(id);
    alert(index);
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.listData.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

  function getSelectedIndex(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listData.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.listData[i].id === id)
        return i;

    }
    return -1;
  }
```